# How to save JSON response data automatically when the response hits the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, response

I send a request to third party URL. After they receive my request, they send a response to my URL. I want to save that data to my table automatically when the response hits my URL.

Response URL format:

```
http://example.com/delivery_reports/new?data=%7B%22requestId%22%3A%22546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567%22%2C%22numbers%22%3A%7B%22911234567890%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222014-11-18+17%3A45%3A59%22%2C%22status%22%3A1%2C%22desc%22%3A%22DELIVERED%22%7D%7D%7D
```

My controller:

```
def new        
    json = JSON.parse(params["data"])    
    requestId = json["requestId"]
    numbers = json['numbers']

    numbers.each do |num| 
      @delivery_report = DeliveryReport.new
      @delivery_report.request_id = requestId
      @delivery_report.date = num[1]["date"]
      @delivery_report.receiver = num[0].to_s
      @delivery_report.status = num[1]["status"]
      @delivery_report.description = num[1]["desc"]
      @delivery_report.save
    end     
  end
```

Data saved to my table when I enter response code directly in URL, but is not saved automatically when URL is hit.

Log:

```
 Started GET "/delivery_reports/new" for 49.207.185.206 at 2015-05-04 09:55:34 +0000
2015-05-04T09:55:34.368716+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-05-04T09:55:34.369910+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/delivery_reports_controller.rb:17:in `new'
2015-05-04T09:55:34.369913+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.369905+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.367718+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeliveryReportsController#new as HTML
2015-05-04T09:55:34.369912+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.369908+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
2015-05-04T09:55:34.657079+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/delivery_reports/new" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=d386f035-9abd-4bce-ae98-696e0038f0cd fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-05-04T09:55:34.655482+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
2015-05-04T09:55:34.648450+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeliveryReportsController#new as HTML
2015-05-04T09:55:34.655478+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.655486+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.655483+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/delivery_reports_controller.rb:17:in `new'
2015-05-04T09:55:34.655485+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-05-04T09:55:34.645606+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/delivery_reports/new" for 49.207.185.206 at 2015-05-04 09:55:34 +0000
2015-05-04T09:55:34.649265+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2015-05-04T09:55:36.207273+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/delivery_reports" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=4f96d14d-b4f4-47dd-af63-44acba98e408 fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=2839
2015-05-04T09:55:36.198316+00:00 app[web.1]:   DeliveryReport Load (10.1ms)  SELECT `delivery_reports`.* FROM `delivery_reports`
2015-05-04T09:55:36.181077+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/delivery_reports" for 49.207.185.206 at 2015-05-04 09:55:36 +0000
2015-05-04T09:55:36.201309+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 14ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 10.1ms)
2015-05-04T09:55:36.186741+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeliveryReportsController#index as HTML
2015-05-04T09:55:36.200260+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered delivery_reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.3ms)
2015-05-04T09:57:49.734086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/delivery_reports" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=967fcaf4-36aa-4c39-ae40-07859d3b9a89 fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=28ms status=200 bytes=2839
2015-05-04T09:57:49.708444+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/delivery_reports" for 49.207.185.206 at 2015-05-04 09:57:49 +0000
2015-05-04T09:57:49.724911+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
2015-05-04T09:57:49.722539+00:00 app[web.1]:   DeliveryReport Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `delivery_reports`.* FROM `delivery_reports`
2015-05-04T09:57:49.720397+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeliveryReportsController#index as HTML
2015-05-04T09:57:49.724189+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered delivery_reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.5ms)
2015-05-04T09:57:49.991163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-0723cb9a2dd5a514d954f70e0fe0b89f6f9f1ae3a375c182f43b5f2b57e9c869.css" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=129f86b0-b6e2-4637-9f5c-cc4bc3df856c fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-05-04T09:57:50.218280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-dfda1387e2621704c9c53ddd9c1573c1f5099fd3108a2a96d2b02d9b79203f15.js" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=38108dcf-fe1f-416e-a013-5692c84a1794 fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-05-04T09:57:52.456405+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/delivery_reports" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=c04fa439-d812-4214-91d6-8d4ca34be7d0 fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=2839
2015-05-04T09:57:52.437697+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/delivery_reports" for 49.207.185.206 at 2015-05-04 09:57:52 +0000
2015-05-04T09:57:52.446959+00:00 app[web.1]:   DeliveryReport Load (1.5ms)  SELECT `delivery_reports`.* FROM `delivery_reports`
2015-05-04T09:57:52.449426+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
2015-05-04T09:57:52.443892+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by DeliveryReportsController#index as HTML
2015-05-04T09:57:52.448588+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered delivery_reports/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
2015-05-04T09:57:52.719122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-0723cb9a2dd5a514d954f70e0fe0b89f6f9f1ae3a375c182f43b5f2b57e9c869.css" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=8efc9c84-b49a-4564-b2d9-b03fabbce459 fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=133
2015-05-04T09:57:52.721796+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-dfda1387e2621704c9c53ddd9c1573c1f5099fd3108a2a96d2b02d9b79203f15.js" host=blooming-plains-7422.herokuapp.com request_id=6de87b4d-12ff-448a-9d2f-38ba6e20a15d fwd="49.207.185.206" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=304 bytes=133
```

Comment: Do you have any validations in your model? Try `save!` - `@delivery_report.save!`. See if it throws any error.

Comment: Is the response sent via GET or POST?

Answer (score 0):

If it works when you access the link via browser but not when the url is hit it's most likely because the API uses POST request.

Add a route to your `routes.rb`:

```
post 'delivery_reports/new', to: 'delivery_reports#new'
```

Comment: do you see the API request in your logs? Can you copy paste it into your question?

Comment: you can probably find it in your logs with something along the lines of `tail -n10000 | grep delivery_reports -A5 -B3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76874/discussion-between-raj-kumar-and-makhan).

Comment: problem is not with route here. The log specified its the problem already in new action.

Comment: yeah, routing was just the most likely guess given the limited information, Raj kumar added the log afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code snippets. This should be the format. Json formatted should be formatted according to rails conventional param names. You can try.

```
if params[:data].present?    
  request = params[:data][:request_id]
  numbers = params[:data][:number]
  #....
```

Possible way to debug:

1. Or you can try to use pry gem and put the `binding.pry` in your action block and then you can check for the right params. And check for your record saving process.
2. You can use a browser based gem to simulate the api hit with same data to generate this issue on your local machine to achieve the desired behavior you are expecting from that exactly same api hit.
3. You can add a raise params.inspect to debug your param also. But that might not give you full information why your code might break.